# All 12 candidates are listed on the elections page after primaries ended

Tags: bug, status-completed, election

During the primaries three people withdrew from the election, but they're showing up as candidates again on the elections page.

Is that intended? I thought at least the primaries were supposed to limit the number of people being voted on to 10. Considering that three people withdrew, I expected to only see 9 candidates remaining for the voting stage.

Comment: Or at the very least the two most negative candidates eliminated if it was ignoring their withdrawal.

Comment: ... well, this is probably bad. Unless there's some exotic, alternate meaning of "withdraw" and "10" I'm not aware of.

Comment: Appears to be fixed now.

Comment: Fixed for me too. (Go vote!)

Comment: Good thing it was fixed or I would've won.  Both spots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to a bug these three withdrawn candidates were put in to the final election.  I have fixed the bug, removed the votes for these candidates, and emailed anyone who cast votes for these three candidates.

Comment: I'm guessing the counter on the side is cached or something, shouldn't it update to reflect that there is now 9 moderator candidates?

Comment: @Thomas Well, there are 12 participating candidates in total, it's just that 3 of them withdrew before the election.